# Find the orthogonal complement on $L^2[0,1]$ of all polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The problem:

**Determine the orthogonal complement on $L^2[0,1]$ to all polynomials.**

My approach and intuition thus far:

I know for sure intuitively that the orthogonal complement would just be the space containing the zero function. I have two approaches to the problem,

(1) I would use the Stone-Weierstrass Approximation theorem to show that the polynomials are dense in the space of functions on $C[0,1]$. Since $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$ the proof would follow by noting the property:
Given a Hilbert Space $V$, the orthogonal complement has the property that:
$V^\perp=\overline{V}^\perp$.

So then I would have to find the orthogonal complement to all functions which is just going to be the zero function.

(2) The other approach I had was to consider the orthogonal basis of all polynomials on $L^2[0,1]$. Then, I would just find the orthogonal complement of the basis.

---

Comment: (1) Correct. You just have to be careful with the two different norms $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$. (2) What basis are you refering to?

Comment: For (2) I was referring to the orthogonal basis of all polynomials.

Comment: Repetitions of what you already phrased don't bring us any further. The truth is that there doesn't exist an "orthonormal basis of all polynomials". I ask again: what do you mean?

Comment: Hm, since you clarified that there doesn't exist an orthonormal basis of all polynomials my statement makes no sense anymore. So I'll scratch off that approach.
What I had considered was that if I could find some basis to all polynomials, then the linear combinations of the basis would make up all of the polynomials. So I would only have to find the orthogonal complement to the basis which would just be $0$.

Comment: The fact that you write "orthogonal basis of all polynomials" tells me that you have not quite understood what you are supposed to in the exercise. Hilbert spaces have orthogonal (better: orthonormal) bases. But the space of all polynomials is not a Hilbert space because it is not complete. It can be seen as a subspace of $L^2[0,1]$, but this subspace is not closed. You have to show that its closure (which is much bigger) is in fact $L^2[0,1]$. However, there are orthonormal bases of $L^2[0,1]$ consisting of polynomials. But showing that their span is dense is in general hard to do.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. So it seems that only my first approach would make reasonable sense to do.

Comment: Yeah, and it's basically one line. You only have to show that the polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$, meaning that you can approximate every $L^2$-function arbitrarily well by a polynomial in the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: Could you leave an answer and I can close the question and check mark the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with route (1) would be the easiest way to go.  If I understand what you mean by (2), i.e., finding a maximal orthonormal set of polynomials and showing that this set of polynomials has no orthogonal complement, doesn't really gain you anything; you still need to show that the orthogonal complement of a set is zero, and you don't gain anything by only considering only an orthonormal subset.